# Assembly: Few Commands in a Single Line

Tags: assembly, x86, dosbox

I have to shorten my code a lot and I thought, whether it is possible to write a few commands in a single line in Assembly x16. For example,

```
MOV cl,10b  CMP cl,10b  JE label
```

I know that it's impossible to write in this way as I've written above, but maybe there is a way to join these commands. Thanks!

This is one of the procedures that I used in my disassembler. I would like to inform you, that I didn't have to identify all commands! I've written all possible variations of commands that I have to identify. THIS IS ONE OF FOUR PROCEDURES, THAT IDENTIFIES COMMAND. I've done this by using this method: I take first two bits of operation code, then divide in four groups (00,01,10,11) and do the same in each group with next to bits and so on.

```
    THIS IS THE PROCEDURE THAT HELPS TO FIND THE OPERATION CODE
 PROC FINDOPK
        opk11:                     ;first two bits of operation coda are 11
                MOV al,opk
                AND al,00110000b
                SHR al,4
                CMP al,01b
                JE opk1101
                CMP al,10b
                JE opk1110
                CMP al,11b
                JE opk1111  ;opk1100 starts here 
                    MOV al,opk
                    AND al,00001100b
                    SHR al,2
                    CMP al,01b
                    JE opk110001
                    CMP al,10b
                    JE opk110010
                    CMP al,11b
                    JE opk110011    ;opk110000 starts here
                        MOV al,opk
                        AND al,00000011b
                        CMP al,10b
                        JE opk11000010
                        CMP al,11b
                        JE opk11000011  ;opk11000000 ir opk11000001
                            JMP neatpazinta   ;it means that i didn't have to identify this command and it prints that
                        opk11000010:  ;Doing stuff if operation code is like this
                            ;
                        opk11000011:  ;Same here
                            ;       
                    opk110001:
                        MOV al,opk
                        AND al,00000011b
                        CMP al,10b
                        JE opk11000110
                        CMP al,11b
                        JE opk11000111  ;opk11000100 ir opk11000101
                            JMP neatpazinta
                        opk11000110:
                            ;
                        opk11000111:
                            ;          
                    opk110010:
                        MOV al,opk
                        AND al,00000011b
                        CMP al,11b
                        JE opk11001011  ;opk11001000 ir opk11001001 ir opk11001010
                            JMP neatpazinta    
                        opk11001011:
                            ;        
                    opk110011:
                        MOV al,opk
                        AND al,00000011b
                        CMP al,01b
                        JE opk11001101
                        CMP al,11b
                        JE opk11001111  ;opk11001100 ir opk11001110
                            JMP neatpazinta
                        opk11001101:
                            ;
                        opk11001111:
                            ;           
                opk1101:
                    JMP neatpazinta
                opk1110: 
                    MOV al,opk
                    AND al,00001100b
                    SHR al,2
                    CMP al,00b
                    JE opk111000
                    CMP al,10b
                    JE opk111010    ;opk111001 ir opk 111011
                        JMP neatpazinta
                    opk111000:
                        MOV al,opk
                        AND al,00000011b
                        CMP al,10b
                        JE opk11100010
                        CMP al,11b
                        JE opk11100011  ;opk11100000 ir opk11100001
                            JMP neatpazinta
                        opk11100010:
                            ;
                        opk11100011:
                            ;
                    opk111010:
                        MOV al,opk
                        AND al,00000011b
                        CMP al,01b
                        JE opk11101001
                        CMP al,10b
                        JE opk11101010
                        CMP al,11b
                        JE opk11101011  ;opk11101000
                            ;
                        opk11101001:
                            ;
                        opk11101010:
                            ;
                        opk11101011:
                            ;        
                opk1111:
                    MOV al,opk
                    AND al,00001100b
                    SHR al,2
                    CMP al,01b
                    JE opk111101
                    CMP al,11b
                    JE opk111111    ;opk111100 ir opk 111110
                        JMP neatpazinta
                    opk111101:
                        MOV al,opk
                        AND al,00000011b
                        CMP al,10b
                        JE opk11110110
                        CMP al,11b
                        JE opk11110111  ;opk11110100 ir opk11110101
                            JMP neatpazinta
                        opk11110110:
                            ;
                        opk11110111:
                            ;
                    opk111111:
                        MOV al,opk
                        AND al,00000011b
                        CMP al,10b
                        JE opk11111110
                        CMP al,11b
                        JE opk11111111  ;opk11111100 ir opk11111101
                            JMP neatpazinta
                        opk11111110:
                            ;
                        opk11111111:
                            ;
            neatpazinta:
                CALL SpausdinkNeatpazinta        
            SkipOPK:
        RET
        FINDOPK ENDP
```

Comment: Please, please.  Do not write assembly code like this.  This does not speed up anything and makes the code a mess to read - even if it will assemble.  Instead, consider having a comment on each individual line explaining what is going on so that higher level programmers can read that instead of trying to parse what they see as "strange alien computer script"

Comment: what's the point? Do you want to shorten your source code, or machine code? If it would be possible to write 3 instructions in single line, they would still compile to the same amount of machine code, so the executable would have same size. If you really need to shorten source, then you can write instead of those above the machine code itself: `db 0xB1, 0x02, 0x80, 0xF9, 0x02, 0x74, 0xF9` (the last `F9` is relative address for jump, so you would have to recalculate+modify it every time, when the label moves). ... but this makes no sense.

Comment: The shortest form of assembly code is of course the raw binary... (but also the shortest code is the code, which does not exists (also it's less buggy!) .. for example the line you wrote is `jmp label` by functionality, no need for 3 instructions).

Comment: BTW, in other assemblers, yes, it is possible to directly compare against a literal and jump in one instruction.  It might be possible in x86 as well, but I'll leave that to experts here to say.

Comment: I've written a dissassembler for about 50 commands I my tutor wants the code to be around 1500 lines. Now I have slightly more than 2000. But still I think that I'll try to explain him that having less rows doesn't mean that it is more efficient.

Comment: having fewer instructions usually does make it more efficient. Especially easier to read, debug and fix (performance implications are very tricky, especially on x86). But that doesn't mean to put 3 instructions on single line, but to simplify logic of your code, and write it in more clear way and with fewer instructions. If you would post some self-contained part as example, maybe it would be possible to asses your current code quality and "density" and give you some hints and advice. (I have strong suspicion that your tutor meant this, to achieve the same task with simpler code)

Comment: Ok, I'll soon post one of my procedures, but it is written in my national language, but I believe you'll still get an idea. I have some thoughts how to shorten my code, but there will be just around 50 lines

Comment: Your tutor clearly meant 1500 instructions, not to find a way to put the same code on fewer source lines.   Hint, use more registers to hold stuff you're working on instead of loading it from memory.  Hoist `mov al, opk` out of all the branch targets into the code that jumps to them.  If a few branch targets don't need it after all, that's fine.  Often doing some redundant work is better than branching more to avoid it.  Especially when you're aiming to simplify the code.

Comment: Unfortunately from the code you posted it's not clear, why you need to differentiate by all those labels, pity you didn't include few major examples what is the target, what you are actually trying to achieve. As this is disassembler, it's more likely you can have this data-driven with having much shorter universal code processing configuration data from table... Although if this is x86 disassembly, then that one is quite pain to generalize, there's always some exception somewhere. But there's 256B intro which is self disassembler... :) http://www.pouet.net/prod.php?which=16930

Comment: For example, I have to disasassemble CD 04.machine code. I read the first byte (this will be my operation code) convert it to binary, which is 11001101. By using my procedure, I go to that label opk11001101, there I'll print that the comand itself is "INT". Next, in the same label, it know that there should be a number of interrupt also, so it reads one more byte, which is a number of INT. I print that number and in the end I come up with answer "INT 04".

Answer (score 1):

Some flavours of x86 assembly syntax allow writing multiple instructions on one line.  For example, GAS (the GNU assembler) uses `;` as a separator.  (`#` is the comment character).

```
.intel_syntax noprefix
MOV cl,10b;   CMP cl,10b;  JE label
```

NASM syntax doesn't allow this, because it's usually not useful.

> I have to shorten my code a lot

In assembly, usually this means you're worried about code-size of the *machine code*, not the size or line-count of the text source.

This means optimizing your code to need fewer and/or shorter instructions.  For ideas, see some of my x86 machine code answers on codegolf.SE, like [Adler32 in 31 bytes of x86-32 machine code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/78896/compute-the-adler-32-checksum/78972#78972).  (NASM source included along with the machine code of course).

In your case, the `je` is always taken so you could probably optimize away most of that and just `jmp label`, depending on what you need `cl` and FLAGS set when you reach `label`.  You could get *exactly* the same architectural state (low byte of ecx = `10b`, ZF set, CF,OF,SF cleared) from this:

```
MOV cl,10b
CMP cl,cl
JE label
```

Interestingly, `je label` may be more efficient than `jmp label` on modern CPUs, because it can macro-fuse with the `cmp` into a single uop.  If `label` doesn't depend on flags being set, then you could do this.

```
MOV cl,10b
JMP label
```

But really, you should step back and look for optimizations at a larger scale, e.g. maybe lay out your branches so you can fall through into `label`.

Comment: I have to cut down from 2200 lines to 1500 lines in my code :/

Comment: @Deividito: Why exactly does line-count have anything to do with anything?  What exactly is imposing that 1.5k limit?  And what assembler are you using?  (NASM?  MASM?  Can you switch to `gas` and put your whole program on one line?  You know that won't change the size of the machine-code at all, right?)

Comment: @Peter Cordes: It would appear to be an artificial limit imposed upon an exercise. Personally I would break out the macros. The sample code has plenty of patterns to be extracted and judicious use might even clear things up.

Comment: @doynax: ah, didn't see the question had been updated when I replied to that comment.